# Getting a set of disjoint regions from the set of overlapping regions

Tags: plotting, regions, logic

Suppose I have two overlapping regions $R1$ and $R2$ looking like this:

```
RegionPlot[{(250 x01 - 433 x02 <= 0 && 
250 x01 - 433 x02 >= -(2000/3) && 683 x01 - 183 x02 >= -400 && 
433 x01 + 250 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
433 x01 + 250 x02 >= 0), (683 x01 - 183 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
683 x01 - 183 x02 >= 0 && 1116 x01 + 67 x02 >= 800/3 && 
433 x01 + 250 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
433 x01 + 250 x02 >= 0)}, {x01, -0.5, 1.5}, {x02, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Now suppose I would like to plot the intersection of those two regions $R1 \land R2 $  as a separate region, together with original regions minus their intersection - i.e. I want to plot the regions $R1 \land R2$, $R1 \land \lnot (R1 \land R2)$, $R2 \land \lnot (R1 \land R2)$ - this can obviously be done via the following command

```
RegionPlot[{(250 x01 - 433 x02 <= 0 && 
 250 x01 - 433 x02 >= -(2000/3) && 683 x01 - 183 x02 >= -400 && 
 433 x01 + 250 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
 433 x01 + 250 x02 >= 0) && (683 x01 - 183 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
 683 x01 - 183 x02 >= 0 && 1116 x01 + 67 x02 >= 800/3 && 
 433 x01 + 250 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
 433 x01 + 250 x02 >= 0), (250 x01 - 433 x02 <= 0 && 
 250 x01 - 433 x02 >= -(2000/3) && 683 x01 - 183 x02 >= -400 && 
 433 x01 + 250 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
 433 x01 + 250 x02 >= 
  0) && ! ((250 x01 - 433 x02 <= 0 && 
    250 x01 - 433 x02 >= -(2000/3) && 683 x01 - 183 x02 >= -400 &&
     433 x01 + 250 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
    433 x01 + 250 x02 >= 0) && (683 x01 - 183 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
    683 x01 - 183 x02 >= 0 && 1116 x01 + 67 x02 >= 800/3 && 
    433 x01 + 250 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
    433 x01 + 250 x02 >= 0)), (683 x01 - 183 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
 683 x01 - 183 x02 >= 0 && 1116 x01 + 67 x02 >= 800/3 && 
 433 x01 + 250 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
 433 x01 + 250 x02 >= 
  0) && ! ((250 x01 - 433 x02 <= 0 && 
    250 x01 - 433 x02 >= -(2000/3) && 683 x01 - 183 x02 >= -400 &&
     433 x01 + 250 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
    433 x01 + 250 x02 >= 0) && (683 x01 - 183 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
    683 x01 - 183 x02 >= 0 && 1116 x01 + 67 x02 >= 800/3 && 
    433 x01 + 250 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
    433 x01 + 250 x02 >= 0))}, {x01, -0.5, 1.5}, {x02, -2, 2}]
```

which results in the output

[image]

My question is - how could I do this for more complicated situations with more than two overlapping regions, as for example, for this set of regions:

```
RegionPlot[{(250 x01 - 433 x02 <= 0 && 
250 x01 - 433 x02 >= -(2000/3) && 683 x01 - 183 x02 >= -400 && 
433 x01 + 250 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
433 x01 + 250 x02 >= 0), (683 x01 - 183 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
683 x01 - 183 x02 >= 0 && 1116 x01 + 67 x02 >= 800/3 && 
433 x01 + 250 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
433 x01 + 250 x02 >= 0), (250 x01 - 433 x02 <= 0 && 
250 x01 - 433 x02 >= -(2000/3) && 683 x01 - 183 x02 <= 0 && 
683 x01 - 183 x02 >= -(2000/3) && 
433 x01 + 250 x02 >= 800/3), (250 x01 - 433 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
250 x01 - 433 x02 >= 0 && 683 x01 - 183 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
683 x01 - 183 x02 >= 0 && 
433 x01 + 250 x02 >= -400), (250 x01 - 433 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
250 x01 - 433 x02 >= 0 && 683 x01 - 183 x02 >= 800/3 && 
433 x01 + 250 x02 <= 0 && 
433 x01 + 250 x02 >= -(2000/3)), (683 x01 - 183 x02 <= 0 && 
683 x01 - 183 x02 >= -(2000/3) && 1116 x01 + 67 x02 >= -400 && 
433 x01 + 250 x02 <= 0 && 
433 x01 + 250 x02 >= -(2000/3)), (683 x01 - 183 x02 <= 800/3 && 
683 x01 - 183 x02 >= -400 && 1116 x01 + 67 x02 <= 800/3 && 
1116 x01 + 67 x02 >= -400 && 433 x01 + 250 x02 <= 800/3 && 
433 x01 + 250 x02 >= -400), (933 x01 - 616 x02 <= 1000 && 
933 x01 - 616 x02 >= -1000 && 1116 x01 + 67 x02 <= 1000 && 
1116 x01 + 67 x02 >= -100 && 183 x01 + 683 x02 <= 1000 && 
183 x01 + 683 x02 >= -1000)}, {x01, -0.5, 1.5}, {x02, -2, 2}]
```

Hence, what I want is a set of disjoint regions, each of which is some intersection of the original regions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use geometric computation tools (`RegionUnion`, `RegionIntersection`, `RegionDifference`) to do so *implicitly*.

Here is what I mean on the smaller example you provided. Let's first create your two regions from the simpler example as `ImplicitRegion` objects and name them for convenience:

```
{region1, region2} = 
 ImplicitRegion[#, {x01, x02}] & /@ {250 x01 - 433 x02 <= 0 && 
    250 x01 - 433 x02 >= -(2000/3) && 683 x01 - 183 x02 >= -400 && 
    433 x01 + 250 x02 <= 2000/3 && 433 x01 + 250 x02 >= 0, 
   683 x01 - 183 x02 <= 2000/3 && 683 x01 - 183 x02 >= 0 && 
    1116 x01 + 67 x02 >= 800/3 && 433 x01 + 250 x02 <= 2000/3 && 
    433 x01 + 250 x02 >= 0};
```

We can then show 1. the intersection between the two; 2. and 3. the difference between the union of the two regions and each of them:

```
RegionPlot[Evaluate@Flatten@
   {
    (* The intersection between the two regions *)
    RegionIntersection[region1, region2],
    (* The two differences, calculated as the union - each region *)
    RegionDifference[RegionUnion[region1, region2], #] & /@ {region1, region2}
   }
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]